# Add cell one + cell two and reset cell two to zero

Tags: vba, excel, google-apps-script

I hope my Intention is clear. It's for inventory management. The first cell Shows the current inventory and the second one is just a cell where you can type in your entries or outflow.  I think the Code for Excel should be something like this, but I'm looking for the corresponding Google spreadsheet:

```
Sub LagerNeu()
    Dim S As Integer
    [F2].Select
    S = ActiveCell.Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ActiveCell.Value = S
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()) method can watch for changes to the `F` column and update the cells as needed

**Example:**

```
function onEdit(e)  {
  var range = e.range; // e.g F2 is edited

  // Only runs if the edit is in column F
  if (range.getColumn() == 6) {  
    var old_value = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
    // Set the new value to the cell in the column to the left - E2
    range.offset(0, -1).setValue(Number(old_value) + Number(e.value));
    // Reset F2 to zero
    range.setValue(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! this is perfect!